# Serializing a class which doesn't implement NSCoding

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I have an objective C program which calls an API to get an objective C class that is implemented by someone else. Lets call the external object O. In my code, I need to serialize O so that it can be encoded and decoded. Can I do this, given that O doesn't implement NSCoding or NSSecureCoding?

Comment: It depends upon how this object was defined, what interface has been provided, whether it may have some internal state that hasn't been exposed, etc. We cannot easily answer this in the abstract. The answer to your question is, unfortunately, it depends.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for an internal library at work whose internals I cannot expose online. Do you have any pointers on what I would be able to serialize and what I wouldn't?

Comment: We don't need to see the actual object. Just an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Bottom line, if it is a simple model object with mutable properties, it will likely be very simple. But if it has complex internal representation or complex interdependencies, it can be another ball of wax.

Comment: Can you encode the info needed to recreate the `O`?

Comment: Understood. Thankfully, I was able to get away with encoding just a uint64 which is a property of the object. So This question has become moot.